# Show progress bar in modal dialog using Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

How do you show a progress bar inside a modal window using twitter bootstrap?
The screen greys out but the modal dialog is not showing.

**JSFiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/jkittell/L0ccmgf2/4/

**HTML**

```
<body>
     <h1>Hello World!</h1>

    <div class="modal hide" id="pleaseWaitDialog" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
        <div class="modal-header">
             <h1>Processing...</h1>

        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="progress progress-striped active">
                <div class="bar" style="width: 100%;"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function () {
    var pleaseWait = $('#pleaseWaitDialog');

    showPleaseWait = function () {
        pleaseWait.modal('show');
    };

    hidePleaseWait = function () {
        pleaseWait.modal('hide');
    };

    showPleaseWait();
});
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use this markup instead:

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="pleaseWaitDialog" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
          <h1>Processing...</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="progress">
          <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success progress-bar-striped" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="40" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 40%">
            <span class="sr-only">40% Complete (success)</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

See [this updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zeroskillz/L0ccmgf2/8/)

Answer (score 9):

Using my extension on [bootstrap-waitingfor](https://github.com/abdennour/bootstrap-waitingfor) library , this extension includes:

- message function
- animate function
- stopAnimate function
- progress function

For more documentation , check this [link](https://github.com/abdennour/bootstrap-waitingfor/blob/master/README.md#using)

---

## For best practices check this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/abdennour/rdzu2o1q/2/) :

```
  waitingDialog.show('In progress ...');
  waitingDialog.progress(0);
 //----i.e: after 2 sec
 waitingDialog.progress(10); // means 10 %
 // i.e: after 2sec again 
 waitingDialog.progress(60); // means 60%
```

### if you want LTR :

```
waitingDialog.show('Please wait',{rtl:false})
```

Comment: "This is the library I am looking for". Kudos to the developer. Clean API, clean documentation, life-saver.

Comment: thanks. Although I found a minor glitch - I used this lib to show progress from an AJAX call. Whenever I got an update in progress I update the progressbar. However the percentage of the bar wasn't show correctly (the value could be 80%, but bar width only 20%). Turning off css transition animation solves the problem. It seems that if the progress() was called while the bar was still animating would disrupt the computation of correct bar width.

Comment: Gang Su - any chance that you might share your code?  Not sure how to turn off css transition animation.  Thanks.